# This simple example breaks abstract class rules?

Tags: java, abstract-class

I do apologise for this, I'm sure everyone is tired of abstract class questions.

Rule/fact: An abstract class cannot be instantiated.

I've come across an example that has me confused:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
    private String name;

    public AbstractClass(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
    //breaking rule
        AbstractClass temp = new AbstractClass("name") {
        };

        System.out.println(temp.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the appropriate language tag to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is the brackets after `new AbstractClass("name")`.

What you are doing is an instantiation of an anonymous inner class. It is **not** the same instantiating an anonymous class. You don't break any rules here. Creating anonymous inner classes can be done with non-abstract classes as well.

What this means is that each time that part of the code is running, you are not only creating a new object of a class, but you are actually creating a new class.

Answer (score 3):

If this is java than you are creating anonymous class here which extends this abstract class. As there is no abstract method so you don't need to implement any method

Answer (score 0):

OP: an Abstract class can not be initialized. It has to be extended into a concrete class to be initializaed by the jvm. You could make Test extend AbstractClass and then pass the name to it, but just trying new on an abstract won't work.

EDIT: I didn't notice the braces on the initializer. The above answer is correct 
    `new Abstract(){};` does create an anon inner.

Comment: What is done here actually works, an anonymous inner class is created.

Comment: No. It doesn't: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The public type AbstractClass must be defined in its own file

 at AbstractClass.<init>(Test.java:1)
 at Test$1.<init>(Test.java:18)
 at Test.main(Test.java:18)

Comment: That error is something completely different. It has nothing to do with actually instantiating the class. You can't have two `public class` within the same file, unless one of them is an inner class to the other.

Comment: Then he entered the question poorly and it needs to be restated.

Comment: For most java programmers I think it is obvious that his classes comes from two different files. I see no need to rephrase the question.

Comment: When you say 'I have found an example...' and then post a single code block example I think it's pretty obvious that it is one block of code.

Comment: I see no reason to continue this discussion. The compilation error you got explains why what you tried did not work.